# Javascript Regex Replace Produces <empty string>

Tags: javascript, input, numbers

I'm kinda at my wits end with this as it is not behaving like other examples I've tried online.

I have some input validation for numbers:

```
$('body').on("input", 'input[type="number"]', function(){
        const regex = /[^0-9]/g;
        const val = $(this).val();
        console.log(val.replace(regex, ''));
```

Any time I enter a character that isn't a digit it returns an `<empty string>` in the console.

[image]

I've tried this same code in a few sandboxes and it works perfectly, returning numbers.

Comment: What happens when you type `4a`?

Comment: Please provide the code we need to reproduce the issue (HTML, valid JavaScript, ...). Note that you currently have an unclosed brace and parenthesis.

Comment: If you're doing this with `<input type=number>`, then an invalid number in the field will cause it to return an empty string as the value.

Comment: As @Pointy points out, the problem has nothing to do with replace. You'll see the same thing if you just do `console.log(val)`.

Comment: This doesn't work with type="number"... It only works with type="text"... Is this documented anywhere? @pointy submit your answer so I can accept it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the value of a `type="number"` input, it returns an empty string if the user input is not a valid number. From the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number))

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty string instead.

Answer (score 0):

The way HTML5 "number" inputs are specified, you're supposed to get nothing (well, the empty string) as the value when it doesn't contain a proper number.

HTML5 validation stuff in general to me seems like it was expressly defined to work without any "oversight" by JavaScript. I'm sure that's an oversimplification of an extremely complicated specification process over years, but it's still true that that's the "rule of thumb" in my head for what to expect.